# React native: React State calls API in another Component continuously

Tags: reactjs, react-native, api, async-await, react-hooks

I made a function component to return data from API. Purpose is to use it throughout my whole app. The code below will show you the structure only (actual code is with graphQL and contains security credentials)

```
async function GetData() {
 console.log("function called")
    try {

     return await fetch('https://www.7timer.info/bin/astro.php?lon=113.2&lat=23.1&ac=0&unit=metric&output=json&tzshift=0')


    } catch (err) 
    { console.log('error fetching data from Source', err) }
  }

export default GetData
```

I call it like the following:

Import:

```
import { useState} from 'react';
import GetData  from "./components/getData";
```

Inside the component:

```
const [data, setData]= useState([]);

 function pullData(){
  GetData().then((result)=>{  
    setData(result);});
}
pullData()
```

What this does it get the data but put requests continually (output in console "function called"). I know it's for the react state. but I just need one result at a time (and any update supplied by graphQL), that's all.

Is there any way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function is called continuously because it will run at each re-render and is being called at every re-render.

Consider wrapping your logic in a useEffect hook to control when the function will be called: https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html

```
useEffect(() => {
    const pullData = async () => {
        GetData().then((result) => {  
            setData(result);
        });
    }
    pullData()
}, [])
```

> If you want to run an effect and clean it up only once (on mount and unmount), you can pass an empty array ([]) as a second argument.

Comment: Oops! I missed that. Thanks a lot.